# TWIG undefined index on Mobile

Tags: php, twig

I have a problem with the TWIG template engine. I can't quite understand what's happening. When i browse trough my page via desktop pc everything works fine but as i use my mobile phone i get always the same three errors.

> undefined index: profile
>   undefined index: site_fees
>   undefined index: account

these are the line which arent properly defined.

```
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable($context["profile"]);
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable($context["site_fees"]);          
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable($context["account"]);
```

This is the whole function

```
 $_parent = $context['_parent'];
    unset($context['_seq'], $context['_iterated'], $context['_key'], $context['page_list'], $context['_parent'], $context['loop']);
    $context = array_intersect_key($context, $_parent) + $_parent;
    // line 81
    echo "
        <div class=\"work-listinfo clearfix cnt\" id=\"profile\">
          <ul>
            ";
    // line 84
    $context['_parent'] = $context;
    $context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable($context["profile"]);
    foreach ($context['_seq'] as $context["_key"] => $context["profile"]) {
        // line 85
        echo "                  <li>
                ";
        // line 86
        if ((session_get("language_id") == 2)) {
            // line 87
            echo "                      <a href=\"";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, base_url(), "html", null, true);
            echo "how_does_it_work/page_description/";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "id", array()), "html", null, true);
            echo "\">";
            echo $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "title_in_french", array());
            echo "</a>
                ";
        } elseif ((session_get("language_id") == 3)) {
            // line 89
            echo "                      <a href=\"";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, base_url(), "html", null, true);
            echo "how_does_it_work/page_description/";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "id", array()), "html", null, true);
            echo "\">";
            echo $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "title_in_german", array());
            echo "</a>
                ";
        } elseif ((session_get("language_id") == 1)) {
            // line 91
            echo "                      <a href=\"";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, base_url(), "html", null, true);
            echo "how_does_it_work/page_description/";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "id", array()), "html", null, true);
            echo "\">";
            echo $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "title_in_english", array());
            echo "</a>
                ";
        } else {
            // line 93
            echo "                      <a href=\"";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, base_url(), "html", null, true);
            echo "how_does_it_work/page_description/";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "id", array()), "html", null, true);
            echo "\">";
            echo $this->getAttribute($context["profile"], "title_in_english", array());
            echo "</a>
                ";
        }
        // line 95
        echo "                  </li>
            ";
    }
```

I don't understand why it works properly on my pc. Does anyone have a clue?

Edit: Its tryed it in a privat tab and still the same issue. Here is the TWIG code.

```
    {% extends 'layouts/home.twig' %}
{% block title %} How it work {% endblock %}
{% block content %}


  <div class="inner-banner">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inner-title">
        <h2>How On Boat Works</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="my-accountcontain content clearfix">


        <aside class="my-accountlf how_te_wrk">
            <div class="dash-boardnav">
              <div class="dash-boardlist">
                <ul>
                  {% for page_list in page_list %} 
                    <li onclick="view_content('{{page_list.id}}')"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="l_{{page_list.id}}">
                      {% if (session_get('language_id')==1) %}
                        {{page_list.pagename_in_english}}
                      {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==2) %}
                        {{page_list.pagename_in_french}}
                      {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==3) %}
                        {{page_list.pagename_in_german}}
                      {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==4) %}
                        {{page_list.pagename_in_spanish}}
                      {% else %}
                        {{page_list.pagename_in_english}}
                      {% endif  %} 
                    </a></li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </aside>

          <aside class="my-accountrh how_te_wrk_rt">
            {% set counter = 0 %}
            {% for page_list in page_list %} 

              {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
              {% set datas = get_how_it_work_page_content(page_list.id) %}

              <div class="work-listinfo clearfix cnt" id="{{page_list.id}}" {% if (counter==1) %}  style="display:block;" {% endif %}>
                  <ul>
                    {% for data in datas %}
                      <li>
                        {% if (session_get('language_id')==2) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{data.id}}">
                              {{ data.title_in_french }}
                          </a>
                        {%  elseif (session_get('language_id')==3) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{data.id}}">
                            {{ data.title_in_german }}
                          </a>
                        {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==1) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{data.id}}">
                            {{ data.title_in_english | raw }}
                          </a>
                        {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==4) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{data.id}}">
                            {{ data.title_in_spanish | raw }}
                          </a>
                        {% else %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{data.id}}">
                            {{ data.title_in_english | raw }}
                          </a>
                        {% endif  %}
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
              </div>

            {% endfor %}

            <div class="work-listinfo clearfix cnt" id="profile">
              <ul>
                {% for profile in profile %}
                  <li>
                    {%  if (session_get('language_id')==2) %}
                      <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{profile.id}}">{{ profile.title_in_french | raw  }}</a>
                    {%  elseif (session_get('language_id')==3) %}
                      <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{profile.id}}">{{ profile.title_in_german | raw  }}</a>
                    {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==1) %}
                      <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{profile.id}}">{{ profile.title_in_english | raw }}</a>
                    {% else %}
                      <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{profile.id}}">{{ profile.title_in_english | raw }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                  </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="work-listinfo clearfix cnt" id="who_we_are_2">
                <ul>
                  {% for site_fees in site_fees %}
                     <li>

                        {%  if (session_get('language_id')==2) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{site_fees.id}}">{{ site_fees.title_in_french | raw  }}</a>
                        {%  elseif (session_get('language_id')==3) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{site_fees.id}}">{{ site_fees.title_in_german | raw  }}</a>
                        {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==1) %}
                          <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{site_fees.id}}">{{ site_fees.title_in_english | raw }}</a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{site_fees.id}}">
                          {{ site_fees.title_in_english | raw }}
                        </a>
                        {% endif  %}


                        </a>
                      </li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="work-listinfo clearfix cnt" id="account">
                 {% for account in account %}
                    {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
                      {% if counter==5 or counter==9  %}
                      </ul>
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if counter==1 or counter==5 %}
                      <ul>
                      {% endif %}
                       <li>
                          {% if (session_get('language_id')==2) %}
                            <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{account.id}}">{{ account.title_in_french | raw  }}</a>
                          {%  elseif (session_get('language_id')==3) %}
                            <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{account.id}}">{{ account.title_in_german | raw  }}</a>
                          {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==1) %}
                            <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{account.id}}">{{ account.title_in_english | raw }}</a>
                          {% else %}
                            <a href="{{base_url()}}how_does_it_work/page_description/{{account.id}}">
                              {{ account.title_in_english | raw }}
                            </a>
                          {% endif %}
                          </a>
                        </li>
                   {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#area-slide").owlCarousel({
     items: 3,
     navigation: true,
     pagination: false,
   });
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
      var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
      $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
    });
  });


  function view_content(id){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#l_'+id).addClass('active');

    $('.cnt').css('display', 'none');
    $('#'+id).css('display', 'block');
  }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should check the source code on your desktop instead of relying on what you see. PHP is rendered on the server and has nothing to do with devices. The notices will be in the source, but just not visible on-screen

Comment: Please add your Twig code in your question (by editing it), it looks like you only added the compiled PHP code.

Comment: The error is clear: you try to access some indexes that don't exist in your array.

Comment: It may be related to sessions. Try to open a private tab/window in your desktop's browser and check if the error also show up.